# Test rpm installation script

Tags: linux, bash, rpm

I'm working on a script that install Apache automatically.
Part of my pre-test is to check that the rpm are installed.
For example to install apache you need zlib and zlib-devel
So basically, I do an `rpm -qa zlib` and then store the output on a variable. Then I repeat the `rpm -qa` but with zlib-devel.
After that I check the versions of the stored variables.
For example: **zlib-1.2.8-3.fc20.x86_64** and **zlib-devel-1.2.8-3.fc20.x86_64**
I break the variable to end with 1.2.8-3.fc20.x86_64, I compare the 2 variables and if its correct the script continues.
The problem is that if there is more that one rpm installed it continues by default. It only checks the first installation.
Is there any simpler way to check the rpm installations?

---

This is the idea of the code:

```
zlib_rpm=`rpm -qa zlib`
if [ -n "$zlib_rpm" ]
then
    zlib_devel_rpm=`rpm -qa zlib-devel*`
    if [ -n "$zlib_devel_rpm" ]
    then
        version_zlib_rpm=`rpm -qa zlib | cut -c 6-`
        version_zlib_devel_rpm=`rpm -qa zlib-devel* | cut -c 12-`
        if [ "$version_zlib_rpm" = "$version_zlib_devel_rpm" ]
        then
            echo "zlib rpm        --> PASSED"
            echo "zlib-devel rpm  --> PASSED"
        fi
    else
        echo "zlib-devel rpm      --> FAILED"
        echo "You can find instructions on how to install rpms on /mw_share/script/instructions/rpm_install"
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "zlib rpm      --> FAILED"
    echo "You can find instructions on how to install rpms on /mw_share/script/instructions/rpm_install"
    exit
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you just use `yum` to install an rpm with its dependencies?

Comment: Mureinik, I have added the code
Robin, sadly by my company rules we need to compile manually each apache. We don't install all the modules that comes with the yum and that is consider a security risk. So the idea of the script is to avoid human error during the apache compilation.

Comment: The normal approach is not to use scripts for this, but rather have your RPM depend on the other packages it need, e.g. add a `Requires: zlib-devel >= 1.2.8` to the .spec file. Is that not a feasible approach.

Comment: @adicaled - does it mean that your apache installation is not packaged after compilation? If your company admins  package it, then nos recommendation above is the best approach.

Comment: Good example where you can use puppet

Answer (score 0):

The `rpm` utility has rich options you can use. In your particular case I'd recommend using `--qf` option. This will allow you to print the version and architecture only avoiding the need to `cut` the output.

```
rpm -q --qf "%{version}.%{arch}\n" zlib
```

If you only want to query the package of specific architecture you can suffix the packagename with x86_64 to query the 64 bit package for example.

```
rpm -q --qf"%{version}.%{arch}\n" zlib.x86_64
```

The `rpm` utility returns non-zero if the package doesn't exist.

Note: You don't need option -a when you are querying for specif package. This option is only for querying all packages.